# Why isn't NetLogo ask parallel?

Tags: parallel-processing, netlogo

i read the documentation of the ask primitive in NetLogo and how it simulates the parallelsim. I also found [here](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Why-Isn't-NetLogo-%22Parallel%22%3F) why NetLogo isn't parallel. Though i still don't understand why just the ask primitive can't be parallel? Can someone please explain me what are the reasons behind this choice?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Both answers below give specific examples where parallel processing would cause errors. At a more theoretical level, parallel processing depends on the ability to break a larger task into smaller tasks that can run independently. But agent-based modelling fundamentally involves interactions between agents, so no independence to exploit. If you don't have interaction, then there is no real point in using the methodology. However, BehaviorSpace - the batch operation of NetLogo - runs the separate simulations in parallel.

Comment: Thank you, with your explanation and Bryan answer, now i understand why it is not so easy as i thought to do a parallel 'ask'

Comment: In short, because parallel programming is very hard and NetLogo needs to be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a large number of technical reasons `ask` cannot be parallel (mostly due to manipulating shared state), but at a high level, consider the following code:

```
create-turtles 3
ask turtles [
  let target one-of other turtles-here
  ask target [
    die
  ]
]
```

Suppose `ask` ran in parallel. Then the different turtles will interweave the execution of the commands in the above `ask` unpredictably (more or less). First, let's look at what we expect to happen. Something like the following (which could happen under current NetLogo semantics):

```
turtle 2 assigns target to turtle 1
turtle 2 asks turtle 1 to die
turtle 1 dies
turtle 0 assigns target to turtle 2
turtle 0 asks turtle 2 to die
turtle 2 dies
```

If `ask` were parallel, however, the following could occur:

```
turtle 2 assigns target to turtle 1
turtle 0 assigns target to turtle 1
turtle 0 asks turtle 1 to die
turtle 1 dies
turtle 2 asks turtle 1 to die, but turtle 1 no longer exists, so an error occurs
```

Thus, if we ran this model in the exact same state twice, one time it might succeed, and another time it might error, just depending of the randomness inherent in parallel execution.

Worse, we can wind up at unexpected states without erroring. Consider the following code that attempts to pair off turtles with links:

```
ask turtles [
  let target one-of other turtles with [ not any? link-neighbors ]
  create-link-with target
]
```

By the same reasoning as above, two turtles may end up connected to the same turtle, resulting in an invalid state of the model, at which point the model will give incorrect results without actually erroring.

Answer (score 1):

What would you want to happen in this case?

```
ask turtles [move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]]
```